# Find free space of a database (sql server)

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to match the result of the following two queries for finding the free space of a database

```
 SELECT 
    sum(size/128.0) AS CurrentSizeMB,  
    sum(size/128.0 - CAST(FILEPROPERTY(name, 'SpaceUsed') AS INT)/128.0 )AS FreeSpaceMB
    FROM sys.database_files

GO
    sp_spaceused
```

Could any suggest me how to modify the first query such that it matches the free space calculated by `sp_spaceused`?

Comment: what's the actual problem you are trying to solve?   EXEC sp_spaceused @updateusage = N'TRUE'

Comment: @CetinBasoz `sp_spaceused` is available in all SQL Server installations. Everyone can just go into the `master` database and read it

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @CONST FLOAT -- To convert the pages to MB
        SELECT @CONST = CONVERT(FLOAT,8)/CONVERT(FLOAT,1024)

        SELECT
        DB_NAME() AS [database],
        f.name AS [file],
        f.size * @CONST AS size,
        FILEPROPERTY(f.name,'spaceused') * @CONST AS allocated,
        (f.size - FILEPROPERTY(f.name,'spaceused')) * @CONST AS unallocated
        FROM sys.master_files f
        JOIN sys.databases d ON d.database_id = f.database_id
        WHERE
        d.name = DB_NAME()

   END
```

Comment: Thanks but it still not matching with the unallocated space by sp_spaceused